# React-bootstrap navbar nav-item, how to align text vertically

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, alignment, react-bootstrap

I've looked for the solution of my problem, but can't find a way to fix the situation without using a custom css class.
I'd like to know if it is possible to do what I'm looking for using only flex classes.

I've this simple navbar component:

```
        <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
                <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            <Nav className="mr-left">
                <Nav.Item >
                        <Timer/>
                </Nav.Item>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar>
```

Where TIMER is a simple `<p>text</p>`.

Is it possible to vertically align this text with align-self: center?
I can't fully get what it is happening.
[image]

Comment: Here it is explained that is possible to have more than one nav inside a navbar without prolems: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676388/multiple-nav-tags 
Now I need to discover how to move just one NAV.ITEM to the right (Float and ml-auto does not work)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way, but I do not like it so much because I've substituted Nav.Item with Nav.Link.. this is not so good:

```
        <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Navbar</Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
                <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link className="disabled ml-auto">
                    <Timer/>
                </Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar>
```

Before I was using 2 nav inside navbar, honestly I do not know how much it is correct.. Instead now I'm using just one NAV but I can't set it as large as the NAVBAR to move the Timer on right

[image]